# Can I run a rake task to simulate sidekiq running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a rails app that I want to use sidekiq on.

Before I figure out how to setup sidekiq on the server etc., is it possible for me to create a rake task that will run the sidekiq workers for any pending jobs?

This isn't a production solution I know, but I just want to make sure everything else is working on the server and for the time being me running a rake task on the server is fine as it is more for QA'ing at this point.

Comment: by "pending jobs", I assume that you already have set up redis in your server in which Sidekiq is going to use, and that the jobs are already in the stored in the redis queue whenever `.perform_async` or `.perform_later` is called. Or if you do not have the redis set up yet, but just want to quickly run a job, then you could simply create a rake task that will run a job inline: i.e. `MyJob.new.perform` or if using ActiveJob: `MyJob.perform_now`

Comment: If however, there are already jobs in the redis queue, and you want to process / run them via the rake task, then I do not know of any simple solution. But, I came up with the following; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into the server, cd to the app's dir and run 'bundle exec sidekiq' manually.

Comment: btw is there a sidekiq support docker image that your company produces by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from
[SortedEntry](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/SortedEntry) and [ScheduledSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/ScheduledSet), I managed to come up with the following:

```
# ScheduledSet returns "pending" jobs
scheduled_jobs = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new

# puts scheduled_jobs.class
# => Sidekiq::ScheduledSet

scheduled_jobs.each do |scheduled_job|
  # puts scheduled_job.class
  # => Sidekiq::SortedEntry

  job_class = scheduled_job.klass.constantize
  job_args = scheduled_job.args

  # you can also filter out only jobs in certain queue, i.e.:
  # if scheduled_job.queue == 'mailers' ......

  # run the job inline
  job_class.new.perform(*job_args)
end
```

Then just wrap this into a rake task.